# Extracting specific columns fullfulling a certain criteria from a data set in SAS

Tags: regex, sas

Completely new to SAS here.

I have a data set with a huge amount of variables. I would like to extract all the variables that for example contains the string "GRP" within its name, and create a new data set from these variables.

EDIT: I do not know any of the variable names, as the data set is huge.

Comment: Show us what you've already tried, example code, etc. Stackoverflow is not a code-on-demand service.

Comment: I am not looking for a code-on-demand service, thank you! My question does not ask for code, so your assumption is wrong. I am looking for a function of some sort which will help me accomplish this task. This task is easily solved in R with names() and grep(), for example. But I am new to SAS, as I also wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first store the variables you're interested into a macro variable and then use them in a keep list. Using data set name work.have as an example to create work.want:

```
/* note the use of use UPPERCASE */
proc sql noprint;
  select name into :varlist separated by ' '
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname='WORK'
    and memname='HAVE'
    and upper(name) contains 'GRP'
  ;
quit;

/* keep only required variables */
data want;
  set have(keep=&varlist);
run;
```

Comment: This assumes I know what the variable names are called. As I wrote, I have a huge amount of variables, and I am not interested in naming each variable I am interested in.

Comment: Amir has given a sufficient & working answer to your question based on your OP.

Comment: If I misunderstood, I apologize. I do not think I understand the first proq sql step, and what it actually does.

Comment: @ErosRam proc sql creates a macro variable called varlist which contains the variables from work.have that contain GRP in the variable name. This is done by looking up dictionary.columns which SAS uses to hold information on the columns of data sets in the SAS system, so you don't need to know the names of the variables or how many there are on the data sets you are interested in. varlist is then used in the keep. See [Accessing SAS System Information By Using DICTIONARY Tables](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/65065/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n02s19q65mw08gn140bwfdh7spx7.htm)